# Moving from XP to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, migration, development-environment

This week I’m going to try and start the move from Windows XP to Windows 7 on my development PC at work.  I’ve downloaded the Windows Easy Transfer app for going from XP to Win7; that should take care of My Documents.  My concern is all of the development environment.  In particular I’m concerned about re-establishing things like my Windows services, which host my WCG services, etc.  They use TCP and various ports.  Plus there are the various ASP.NET apps that are on my machine.  What caveats should I be aware of, before I start this?

Comment: I don't think this belongs on superuser. He is asking specifically about development environment issues.

Answer (score 15):

I deeply don't recommend you to migrate. If I were you, I'd backup these files, format the PC, reinstall everything back again and re-set up the websites. No matter how much pain that may cause, it's still less pain then the potential one you might get if you use this migration tool rather than doing it properly, which would eventually cause you to do the right way anyway.

Comment: +100. Reformat and install it. You'll be happier, and so will those around you.

Comment: Agree with these smart guys.  You could also just back it up, and install slackware. :V

Comment: I did this just last week and would also recommend a clean install. I didn't do a clean install on one of my computers and small irritating permissions and file ownership bugs popped up. There are also differences between IIS 6 and IIS 7 that will need to be overcome anyway, so best just do it from scratch.

Comment: The Easy transfer tool works well for the typical average home user. It will transfer your user profile correctly, but that that's about it.

Comment: You are correct, I will wipe my machine clean and install the OS that way, rather than try to do an upgrade.

What are the issues involved going from IIS 6 to IIS7?

Comment: Clean install is the way to go! +1